# Filter DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, collectionviewsource

I tried to filter DataGrid. But `viewSource.View.Refresh()` was not called.

Why?

Although text `ComboBox_SelectionChanged` printed:

```
private CollectionViewSource viewSource;
public ObservableCollection<Event> Events = new ObservableCollection<Event>();
public ReportWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();            
    Task t = GetEventsFromDBAsync(FromDate, ToDate);
    t.Wait();

    viewSource = new CollectionViewSource
    {
        Source = Events
    };

    viewSource.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(ViewSource_Filter);
    ICollectionView Itemlist = viewSource.View;
    EventsDataGrid.ItemsSource = Itemlist;  
}

void ViewSource_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("filter");
}
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    viewSource.View.Refresh();
    Console.WriteLine("ComboBox_SelectionChanged");
}
```

Comment: try calling `Rebind` on the datagrid

Comment: I add `EventsDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;            EventsDataGrid.ItemsSource = viewSource.View; ` in `ComboBox_SelectionChanged` but "filter" not printed. "filter" was printing when window initialized

Comment: hmm..I Rebuilded solutions and It started to work